# Excel: Create a Future Date Based On a Score

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to calculate future dates based on a numerical score. The spreadsheet has an inspection date and a score of 1-3. If the score is 1 then I want the cell to display a date 30 days after the inspection date. If the score is 2 then I want the cell to display a date 60 days after the inspection. And if the score is 3 then I want the cell to display a date 90 days after the inspection. Can you give me an example of the IF statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I assume that inspection date is in `A2` and score is in `B2`, then this should work without the need for an `IF` statement:

`=A2+(B2*30)`

which just adds the number of days to the original date, based on 30 times score.

Don't forget to format the cell the formula is in to date format.

**UPDATE**

If you don't always have that direct of a relationship, then you can use `CHOOSE`.

`=A2+CHOOSE(B2,30,60,90)`

Here `B2` is used to select the appropriate value in your list of values `30,60,90` such as if `B2` is `2` then the second value is returned.